# Class not being found online but works locally -- CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Class' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am getting this error after uploading my web app to my Rackspace box.

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It's odd because it works fine on my local computer where I do development.  The actual line of code is:

```
public User user = new User();
```

I am using C#.

Comment: A few questions: 1. Is this a compiled web application (one or more DLLs in the /bin folder) or a web site (lots of .cs files in the /App_Code folder)? 2. What namespace is User in - is it the framework or your own class? 3. What using statements do you have on the class? 4. What version of IIS are you running on?

Comment: I'd be guessing that the class User is defined in an assembly that is in your local machine's GAC, but not on the Rackspace box's GAC...?  HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is because Rackspace will be running your application in Medium Trust mode, and on your machine your application will have full trust.

Without a lot more to go on, it'll be difficult to diagnose exactly what's going wrong, but perhaps these links will give you some insight?

[How To: Use Medium Trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998341.aspx)  (read "Medium Trust Summary" about a page down).

[Someone running into the same issues](http://forums.asp.net/t/1201680.aspx).

Comment: @womp: Rackspace will happily give you a server, so your guess that his app will be running in Medium Trust mode may be incorrect.